# c# access idle workflow data

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow application which is use sql persistence for the idled workflows and I am using PersistenceParticipant in order to store some values of the idle workflows. I want to Load a gridview which will load all the idle workflow instances according to the PersistenceParticipant values of each one. Do you have any ideas how to approach this idea?. 
Thx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The promoted properties are stored in the InsertPromotedProperties table in SQL Server using the columns Value1, Value2 etc. You can query that table and determine the workflows that satisfy your filter based on the values there.